# Does deepstream requires login after reconnect?

Tags: deepstream.io

I am building a service which would depend on maintaining a unique session ID for the connected clients. Currently I am using the login() method to return sessionID as a part of userData from deepstream authentication handler.

When a client(in browser) disconnects and reconnects due to bad network will the login call be made again? In that case a new sessionID will be generated which is undesirable.

Answer (score 2):

deepstream will internally cache the authentication data and re-send them upon reconnecting. However, if establishing a connection fails continuously and the connection closes with an error state you'd have to call `.login()` again manually.